# Save part of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nsdictionary

I have a `NSDictionary` with a `NSString` and `NSArray`

I have to save only the `NSArray` in a variable without knowing the key.

Is this possible?

Comment: Just curious as to why you need to do this; perhaps there's a simpler design solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a dictionary that contains both an NSString and an NSArray, and you want to extract just the NSArray, without knowing what the key is.

One way to do that is to look through the dictionary with fast enumeration:

```
NSString *key;
for(key in someDictionary){
     id someObject = [someDictionary objectForKey: key];
}
```

and then look at the objects to see which one is an NSArray:

```
    if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        // do something with the array
    }
```

(obligatory warning: explicitly checking an object's class is often a sign of a flawed design. In most cases, you should be checking for behavior (`-respondsToSelector`), not class identity)

Comment: isMemberOfClass i don't know this method! Fantastic Thx a lot

Comment: You might also want to check out isKindOfClass, which covers subclasses too.

Comment: I believe you'd need to use `-isKindOfClass`; `NSArray` is abstract.